# Cell Values Disappear After "End With" Is Executed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing a weird dilemma where the cell values disappear as soon as the code hits End With line. (As pointed out by Spinner, it's the .Value line making the values disappear).

I have a complex structure of code execution, and the same code to input cell values is already being used elsewhere in the code correctly with minor difference. This one is working under Nested For/If Loops and the column names and value reference is changed as per the requirement.

Can't seem to figure out the issue. Check Column X in the GIF below.

[image: Values Disappearing]

```vb
    With Processed
    Processed.Activate
    Processed.AutoFilterMode = False
    Processed.ShowAllData
    Range("J:J").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("J:J").Value = Range("J:J").Value
    Range("K:K").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("K:K").Value = Range("K:K").Value
    Range("L:L").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("L:L").Value = Range("L:L").Value
    Range("M:M").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("M:M").Value = Range("M:M").Value
    Range("O:O").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("O:O").Value = Range("O:O").Value
    Range("P:P").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    Range("P:P").Value = Range("P:P").Value
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
    Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("J1").Value = "DATE 1"
    Range("K1").Value = "DATE 2"
    Range("M1").Value = "DATE 3"
    Range("N1").Value = "DAY 1"
    Range("Q1").Value = "DAY 2"
    Range("R1").Value = "BUSINESS UNIT"
    Range("S1").Value = "DC TIME DIFFERENCE"
    Range("T1").Value = "EXCLUDING FREEZING TIME (SAT-THU)"
    Range("U1").Value = "EXCLUDING FREEZING TIME (FRI)"
    Range("V1").Value = "EXCLUDING FREEZING TIME (OVERALL)"
    Range("W1").Value = "M-CUST TIME"
    Range("X1").Value = "M-CUST TIME EXCLUDING FREEZING TIME (SAT-THU)"
    Range("Y1").Value = "M-CUST TIME EXCLUDING FREEZING TIME (FRI)"
    Range("Z1").Value = "M-CUST TIME EXCLUDING FREEZING TIME (OVERALL)"
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    lLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lLastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set TblRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(lLastRow, lLastColumn))
    Set Tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TblRng, xlYes)
    Tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
    LastRow = Processed.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    For Each i In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Range("E" & i.Row).Value = "M-CUST" Then
            InciNum = Range("A" & i.Row).Value
            TaskNum = Range("F" & i.Row).Value
            Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=InciNum, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            For Each j In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If TaskNum < Range("F" & j.Row).Value And Range("E" & j.Row).Value <> "Cancelled" Then
                    Range("M" & j.Row).Value = Range("L" & j.Row).Value + 1
                End If
            Next j
        End If
        Next i
    Processed.ShowAllData
    
    For Each i In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        StartDate = Range("L" & i.Row).Value
        EndDate = Range("P" & i.Row).Value
        Range("S" & i.Row).Value = DateDiff("n", StartDate, EndDate)
        Range("N" & i.Row).Value = Format(StartDate, "dddd")
        Range("Q" & i.Row).Value = Format(EndDate, "dddd")

        If Range("S" & i.Row).Value < 0 Then
            Range("S" & i.Row).Value = 0
        End If
    Next i
    
    For Each i In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If Range("E" & i.Row).Value = "M-CUST" Then
            StartDate = Range("P" & i.Row).Value
            InciNum = Range("A" & i.Row).Value
            TaskNum = Range("F" & i.Row).Value
            Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=InciNum, Operator:=xlFilterValues
            For Each j In Range("A2:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If TaskNum < Range("F" & j.Row).Value And Range("E" & j.Row).Value <> "Cancelled" Then
                    EndDate = Range("O" & j.Row).Value
                    Range("W" & i.Row).Value = DateDiff("n", StartDate, EndDate)
                    If .Range("R2").Value Like "B2B" Then
                        TimeUpr2 = TimeSerial(22, 0, 0)
                    Else
                        TimeUpr2 = TimeSerial(23, 0, 0)
                    End If
    
                    With .Range("X2")
                        sDateIni = Range("P" & i.Row).Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
                        sDateEnd = Range("O" & j.Row).Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
                        sFmlHours = kFmlHours
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#INI", sDateIni)
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#END", sDateEnd)
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#LWR", TimeLwr)
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#UPR", TimeUpr)
                    End With
                    With .Range("X2:X" & LastRow)
                        .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
                        .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
                    End With
                    With .Range("Y2")
                        sDateIni = Range("P" & i.Row).Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
                        sDateEnd = Range("O" & j.Row).Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
                        sFmlHours = kFmlHours2
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#INI", sDateIni)
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#END", sDateEnd)
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#LWR", TimeLwr2)
                        sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#UPR", TimeUpr2)
                    End With
                    With .Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow)
                        .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
                        .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
                    End With
                    For Each ii In Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                        .Range("Z" & i.Row).Value = .Range("X" & i.Row).Value + .Range("Y" & i.Row).Value
                    Next ii
                End If
            Next j
            End If
        Next i
    Processed.ShowAllData
    
    If .Range("R2").Value Like "B2B" Then
        TimeUpr2 = TimeSerial(22, 0, 0)
    Else
        TimeUpr2 = TimeSerial(23, 0, 0)
    End If
    
    With .Range("T2")
            sDateIni = Range("L2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sDateEnd = Range("P2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sFmlHours = kFmlHours
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#INI", sDateIni)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#END", sDateEnd)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#LWR", TimeLwr)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#UPR", TimeUpr)
    End With
    With .Range("T2:T" & LastRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
            .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
    End With
    With .Range("U2")
            sDateIni = Range("L2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sDateEnd = Range("P2").Address(0, 1, xlR1C1, False, .Cells)
            sFmlHours = kFmlHours2
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#INI", sDateIni)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#END", sDateEnd)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#LWR", TimeLwr2)
            sFmlHours = Replace(sFmlHours, "#UPR", TimeUpr2)
    End With
    With .Range("U2:U" & LastRow)
            .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
            .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
    End With
    For Each i In Range("V2:V" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Range("V" & i.Row).Value = .Range("T" & i.Row).Value + .Range("U" & i.Row).Value
    Next i
    Range("S:S").NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("T:T").NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("U:U").NumberFormat = "General"
    Range("V:V").NumberFormat = "General"
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The `With` statements are all referencing a worksheet from a previous `With` statement that is not in the code you shared. eg `With .Range("X2")` - What worksheet is this Range a member of? I notice that none of the `Range` objects referenced outside of the `With` statements are not referencing any worksheet. eg `Range("A1").AutoFilter` - What worksheet is `ActiveSheet` during the execution?

Comment: @Toddleson there are two worksheets; Main and Processed. All of this is happening inside the Processed worksheet (all of the code that has been posted here that is). Processed worksheet stays active during all the execution.

Comment: Does sFmlHours have a valid formula?

Comment: @Toddleson yes, I'm using a constant formula declaration and then substituting here.

Comment: Ok, I can't see any glaring issues, and its hard to deeply inspect the code while not being able to run it. Hopefully someone else can find the error.

Comment: In the first code part the initial ´with´ is not visible. I would check that. I think it is an issue mixing ´range´and ´.range´

Comment: You really need to include the outer `With`/`End With` here.  Also all of these unqualified `Range()` calls are asking for bugs.

Comment: Added the full section of the code that gets worked on (Processed)

Comment: Your use of `With` blocks is all over the place (many things are missing the leading `.`) - your code needs a significant clean-up to resolve the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

Man, but that gif approach is eye watering. :)
Still, managed to figure out a basic interpretation problem:
o  The values disappear on execution of the line above the End With
o  i.e. it's when you step to the End With (not when that line is executed)
o  That means .Value = .Value is what's clearing the cells (not the End With)

And that of course makes sense, as End With does nothing other than just that.

Can't figure out why the particular data in the 'view' provided is cleared.
 But, as Toddleson says, not being able to directly test the code makes working that out nigh on impossible.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! It's the .Value line. I guess in the moment of exhaustion I just interpreted it as that.

Comment: Good oh. Then mahaps make this as answered (saves other like me having to read through to work that out).

Comment: The issue still persists. Regardless of what I have written as what I interpreted.

Comment: Yeah. Perhaps. Though strictly speaking, your question was why End With was causing this. Which of course I've answered. If the above didn't steer you to the cause, and you now have a different question, suggest posting that as a separate question. And, for us to sort that out, you need to provide the additional info required for us to to actually work out what's wrong. That means we need the full picture (not a tiny window into only part of the picture). : )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dumping the data to a text file on each iteration of the i/j loop for further examination.

```vb
With .Range("X2:X" & LastRow)
        .FormulaR1C1 = sFmlHours    'Enter formula
         dump i, j, .Offset() '<--- add line here
        .Value = .Value             'Replace Formula with Value
End With

Sub dump(i, j, rng As Range)
    Dim fso, ts, c, s As String
    s = Format(Now, "HHMMSS") & "_i" & i & "_j" & j & ".txt"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.createTextFile("dump_" & s)
    With ts
        .writeline "Range= " & vbTab & rng.Address(External:=True)
        .writeline "i= " & i & vbTab & "j= " & j
        For Each c In rng
            .writeline c.Address & vbTab & c.Value2 & vbTab & c.FormulaR1C1
        Next
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem will go away when you edit the code.
I would suggest at least the following steps:

- correct indenting to have an overview what is referenced by `with` (e.g. after the first `with` there are no indents - i assume that's why you didn't copy it the first time)
- use clear variable names, e.g. from looking at the code it is not clear (at one glance) that `processed` is a sheet, I suggest using `wsProcessed`
- get rid of all implicit range references - make them all explicit by referencing the according sheet.
- use sub routines for repeating code parts with clear names describing the task of the routine and well-named parameters
- maybe configuration/mapping arrays could help also to get shorter code  - e.g. one for the formatting per column, one for the caption etc.
- maybe it would help to have an enum that defines the columns - so that you reference the column by "speaking" enums not by an abstract "A", "B", like this:

```vb
' at the top of the module

private enum colSheetXXX
   cXXX_Date1 = 1   '= column A
   cXXX_Date2 = 2   '= column B
   'proceed like this with all columns
   cXXX_BusinessUnit = 
end enum
```

Then you can address a column like this: `ws.Columns(cXXX_BusinessUnit)`

And if, at any time, the order of the columns changes or new columns have to be inserted you just have to do add them to the enum or change the order of the enum - without looking into the rest of the code :-)

If the mysterious empty cell still is there after refactoring it should be much easier to find the source of the error.

Hoping this is not too "Oberlehrerhaft" (know-all) as we say in Germany

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve disappearing formulas by first using trial and error to find what section of code was causing the problem.  For example, I cut each section and then tried entering =B4 instead of usual formula to see if it survived execution. Then, I: Cut the problem code in VBA > input my sheet formulas > used Undo to replace the cut VBA code.